# get vimrc or init.vim defined by -u switch in vim/neovim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

According to `:help starting`, we can specify a specific vimrc file using the following command

```
$ vim -u /path/to/vimrc
```

How can I access the path of that vimrc/init.vim file in vim/neovim?

I have tried the following.

```
expand('%:p')     " returns different path based on opened file
stdpath('config') " returns default vimrc or init.vim path
$MYVIMRC          " it is not set when using -u switch
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
:echo index(v:argv, '-u') != -1 ? get(v:argv, index(v:argv, '-u') + 1, '') : ''
```

Require the patch [8.1.2233](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2233).  See [`:h v:argv`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#v:argv).

At this moment, Neovim 0.4.4 does not have the patch and Neovim 0.5.0 has the patch.

Comment: Perfect for VIM. With neovim (0.4.4) I got `E121: Undefined variable: v:argv`.

Comment: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/e89462d9855eef7718d482df7f92da4279a1c5c3

Comment: Works in Neovim nightly (0.5.0).